# Python syntax highlighter for Python

Tags: python, syntax-highlighting

Is there a simple (possibly with no dependencies) syntax highlighter witch tokenizes Python source code? I need it to return the token type, the offset from the beginning of the code and token length.

I wanted to use Python build-in `tokenize` but it does not return the offsets.

I also looked to a few of standard syntax highlighters but they all tokenize other languages as well, which is overkill for my case. All I'm looking for is simple (and fast) Python syntax highlighter.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know about the offset but you can get back a stream of tokens from a Python snippet using [pygments](http://pygments.org/). It's a single standalone Python library as far as I know. The stream of tokens can then be used to do whatever you want. I have an [example](https://gist.github.com/773300) that renders a snippet of Python onto a pygame surface with syntax highlighting using Pygments. It tokenises the input line by line.

Comment: pygments is slow, very slow, not worth if you want performance

Comment: use `pysyntect` for fast computation, the library is made in rust, but can be accesible from python code

Answer (score 2):

Checkout http://oneqonea.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-do-i-add-syntax-highlighting-to-my.html

It's a really easy "SyntaxHighlighter for Blogger" tutorial with screenshots and everything.

You should be up and running in only a few minutes.

In your case since you're looking for a "simple (and fast)" syntax highlighter without any unnecessary overhead, on your implementation simply include only the shBrushPython.js library file like this:

```
<head>
    <script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushPython.js' type='text/javascript'/>
</head>
```

Hope this helps. Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted it to be in Python.